# Multiple occurance regex PHP latin signs

Tags: php, regex

In Javascript I replace all occurances of the letter 'ą' to '**aaa**'.

```
 json=json.replace(/\ą/g,'**aaa**');
```

Now I would like to do it backwards in PHP, changing all '**aaa**' to 'ą'.

For Example:

```
**aaa**baba**aaa**  for 'ąbabaą';
```

It is probably easy but I am not good at PHP.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to escape `ą`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace), like this:

```
$string = str_replace( '**aaa**', 'ą', $string);
```

If you need word boundaries, you'd need a regex, like this one:

```
$string = preg_replace( '/\b**aaa**\b/', 'ą', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$original = "**aaa**baba**aaa**";
$result = str_replace("**aaa**", "ą", $original);
```

Note that PHP's web site has a great search feature; in this case I typed "http://php.net/replace" to get a list of entries related to "replace", and the first link was for the above function.

Comment: I found it but it didnt work - sry for bothering all of you - the problem was i didnt attache header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: No bother at all -- consider editing your question with the new information, and then posting your solution as an answer. Someone might be Googling for a similar problem, and your experience can help them out.